# how to use msgbox to display 3X9 range of cells with both text and values

Tags: vba, excel

looking for some help with displaying a 3x9 range of cells with both text and values in a message box function or another function that will do the same?

msgbox sheets.("solver").range("f30:g38").value

Comment: That is only **2 X 9**

Comment: ***E30:G38 @Gary'sStudent

Comment: Why a message box? Wouldn't a user form and list box be more appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

This will produce and output of the cells from **F30** through **H38**:

```
Sub mesage()
    Dim msg As String
    msg = ""
    For i = 30 To 38
        For Each a In Array("F", "G", "H")
            msg = msg & Cells(i, a).Value & vbTab
        Next a
        msg = msg & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Adjust for any reasonable range:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you are having *Dim* problems then:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mesage()
    Dim msg As String, i As Long, a As Variant
    msg = ""
    For i = 30 To 38
        For Each a In Array("F", "G", "H")
            msg = msg & Cells(i, a).Value & vbTab
        Next a
        msg = msg & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response!  I tried copying and pasting the code, but it would not work. @gary'sstudent

Comment: What happened??  Did you have macros enabled??

Comment: when I run the debugger f8 it says " i " and "a" are not defined @gary'sStudent

Comment: Dim "i" and "a" as Integer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again for the quick feedback!  @Gary'sStudent

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Is there a way for the cells to display in a grid, rather than floating?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I seem to have come across a few issues, while  expanding my current model. 1) expanding from 3x9 to 16x8. I added the columns "C"-"R" and i = 56 to 63 but it stacks on top of one another. 2) also, I needed to switch from solver to opensolver but when I call RunOpenSolver in my VB userfrom it gives an error but when I try it in a macro it works fine? any guidance would be greatly appreciated. As to my original question, I wanted to know if I could have the displayed cells in boxes or cells as they look in the excel spread sheet..

Comment: @A.c.Weiman ............I don't know the answer to this one............I suggest you open a new question............